# I want to attach my robot upside-down

Tags: ros, moveit, kuka

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I want to change the base position.

[image: image description]

In this given example, I want to attach my robot upside facing towards down. I there any way to do it?

I have tried changing the urdf file, but the robot orientation and linking all joints 180 degrees was causing the problem.  Any easy idea to achieve this type of result?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from kr16_2.xacro                   | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!--Generates a urdf from the macro in kr16_2_macro.xacro -->
<robot name="kuka_kr16_2" xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">
  <!-- LINKS -->
  <!-- base link -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="3.14 0 0" xyz="0 0 2.35"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="3.14 0 0" xyz="0 0 2.35"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/base_link.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="3.14 0 0" xyz="0 0 2.35"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/base_link.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 1 (A1) -->
  <link name="link_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_1.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_1.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 2 -->
  <link name="link_2">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_2.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_2.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 3 -->
  <link name="link_3">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_3.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_3.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 4 -->
  <link name="link_4">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_4.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_4.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 5 -->
  <link name="link_5">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_5.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_5.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- link 6 -->
  <link name="link_6">
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="2"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/visual/link_6.dae"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kuka_kr16_support/meshes/kr16_2/collision/link_6.stl"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <!-- tool 0 -->
  <!-- This frame corresponds to the $FLANGE coordinate system in KUKA KRC controllers. -->
  <link name="tool0"/>
  <!-- END LINKS -->
  <!-- JOINTS -->
  <!-- joint 1 (A1) -->
  <joint name="joint_a1" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="3.14 0 0" xyz="0 0 1.675"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="link_1"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1.35"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-3.22885911619" upper="3.22885911619" velocity="2.72271363311"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- joint 2 (A2) -->
  <joint name="joint_a2" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.26 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_1"/>
    <child link="link_2"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-2.70526034059" upper="0.610865238198" velocity="2.72271363311"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- joint 3 (A3) -->
  <joint name="joint_a3" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.68 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_2"/>
    <child link="link_3"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-2.26892802759" upper="2.68780704807" velocity="2.72271363311"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- joint 4 (A4) -->
  <joint name="joint_a4" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.67 0 -0.035"/>
    <parent link="link_3"/>
    <child link="link_4"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-6.10865238198" upper="6.10865238198" velocity="5.75958653158"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- joint 5 (A5) -->
  <joint name="joint_a5" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_4"/>
    <child link="link_5"/>
    <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-2.26892802759" upper="2.26892802759" velocity="5.75958653158"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- joint 6 (A6) -->
  <joint name="joint_a6" type="revolute">
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="link_5"/>
    <child link="link_6"/>
    <axis xyz="-1 0 0"/>
    <limit effort="0" lower="-6.10865238198" upper="6.10865238198" velocity="10.7337748998"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- tool frame - fixed frame -->
  <joint name="joint_a6-tool0" type="fixed">
    <parent link="link_6"/>
    <child link="tool0"/>
    <origin rpy="0 1.57079632679 0" xyz="0.158 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <!-- END JOINTS -->
  <!-- ROS base_link to KUKA $ROBROOT coordinate system transform -->
  <link name="base"/>
  <joint name="base_link-base" type="fixed">
    <origin rpy="3.14 0 0" xyz="0 0 2.35"/>
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base"/>
  </joint>
</robot>
```

I have just changed rpy, xyz of base_link and  rpy, xyz , and child axis xyz of  joint_a1

Solved but confused with the base_link. It should be Either it should be on the top near a base location?

[image: image description]

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372003/i-want-to-attach-my-robot-upside-down/) by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1622 on 2021-02-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-02-17**:
Please show how you changed the URDF file and what error you received.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-17**:
Apart from the fact you're using a KUKA, this reads like a duplicate of #q321902.

If you agree, please close your question as such.

Edit: it might be good to change the title of your question to "I want to attach my robot upside-down". The current title asks about a possible solution, which is typically regarded as an [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-17**:
Please post updates by *appending* to in your original question text. Do not use comments for this.

Use the `edit` button/link under your original post to update it.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-02-17**:
I am sorry was not knowing that we can edit the original question post. I am not able to delete this comment. I am getting 10 minutes posting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have just changed rpy, xyz of base_link and rpy, xyz , and child axis xyz of joint_a1

It appears you've edited the *existing* `base_link-base` transform (ie: `joint`):

> ```
> <!-- ROS base_link to KUKA $ROBROOT coordinate system transform -->
> ```

```
<link name="base"/>
<joint name="base_link-base" type="fixed">
  <origin rpy="3.14 0 0" xyz="0 0 2.35"/>
  <parent link="base_link"/>
  <child link="base"/>
</joint>
```

that's not what #q321902 suggests and I would strongly recommend not to do that.

From that Q&A:

> Create a new `.xacro` file, import the robot macro `.xacro` as you'd normally do.
>
> Then create the `fixed` joint that you'd normally create to place the robot in your scene, but instead of using an identity transform (ie: `xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"`) specify a Z-offset (to translate it "into the air"), then rotate it over either the Y or the X axis by 180 degrees and make the robot's `base_link` the `child` frame.

The important parts are:

- create a *new* `.xacro` (so do not edit any existing files)
- *add* a `joint`, make it of `type=fixed`
- set the `parent link` to the name of the `link` you want to attach your robot model to
- set the `child link` to the first link of the robot model

The "first link of the robot model" is always called `base_link` in the models found in `ros-industrial/kuka_experimental`. The `base_link` is in general the "start of a model" in ROS. There is nothing special about `base_link` (it's just another `link` as far as the URDF parser is concerned), but by *convention* (ie: an implicit agreement among users), we always start robot models with it in ROS.

In the model you're using (from `ros-industrial/kuka_experimental`), there is also a `base` link. Things can get a little confusing here, as KUKA itself also defines a *Base* frame. Those two are not identical however, and you'll want to make sure you are referring to the correct frame when talking to other ROS users, as they will not know what a KUKA *Base* frame is necessarily.

Unfortunately, there isn't a REP about frame names for industrial robots in ROS yet, but for now perhaps [Coordinate Frames for (Serial Industrial) Manipulators](http://gavanderhoorn.github.io/rep/rep-0199.html#coordinate-frames) could help shed some light on this (ignore the *Vendor Nomenclature Mapping* section, it's incorrect). This is not an active REP, but a document on the conventions we've used in ROS-Industrial.

Now back to your question:

> Solved but confused with the base_link. It should be Either it should be on the top near a base location?

The example in #q321902 has this:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" ?>
> <robot name="upside_down_m10ia" xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">
>   <xacro:include filename="$(find fanuc_m10ia_support)/urdf/m10ia_macro.xacro"/>
> >       <xacro:fanuc_m10ia prefix="robot_"/>
> >     
> >       <link name="world" />
> >       <joint name="ceiling_joint" type="fixed">
> >         <origin xyz="0 0 2" rpy="0 ${radians(180)} 0" />
>     <parent link="world" />
>     <child link="robot_base_link" />
>   </joint>
> </robot>
> ```

The idea is to consider the robot model immutable (ie: you never touch it, it's read-only), and you attach it to other geometry in your robot cell (ie: the metal frame) by *adding* additional `joint`s.

You don't show us the URDF for the metal frame you show in your picture, but with the structure shown in the example here, you'd probably replace `world` (ie, the `parent link`) with the name of whatever `link` you have in your metal frame where the robot should be mounted.

Summarising: don't edit the `base_link-base` joint in the `kuka_kr16_2` `xacro:macro`, but attach the robot model to your metal frame by using an additional joint. That will result in the `base_link` of the robot model to be in the right place.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-17**:
I would also recommend not to convert the files to URDF, but keep working with the `.xacro`s directly. Xacro is much more flexible, as it allows to combine different xacro fragments in an easy way. URDF cannot be combined with anything else.

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-02-18**:
Thanks for the help! and once again sorry was not knowing about the ticking. Thanks for helping me

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-18**:
No need to apologise.